# Python Tkinter Button with If Else statements

Tags: python, if-statement, button, tkinter

I want to bind the `Start_Button` with 2 possible functions:

If `Choice_1_Button` is clicked and then the `Start_Button`, the `Start_Button` should call `foo1`. But when the user clicks `Choice_2_Button` then the same `Start Button` should call `foo2`.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
Choice_1_Button=Button(root, text='Choice 1', command=something) #what should it do?
Choice_2_Button=Button(root, text='Choice 2', command=something_else)
Start_Button=Button(root, text='Start', command=if_something) #and what about this?
```

Does anyone know what `something`, `something_else` and `if-something` should do?

Comment: Just call a single function. In that function query your Radiobuttons variable with `var.get` and call apropriate function (`func1()` or `func2()`).

Answer (score 0):

The following code keeps track of what they pressed:

```
choice=None
def choice1():
    global choice
    choice='Choice 1'
def choice2():
    global choice
    choice='Choice 2'
def start():
    global choice
    if choice=='Choice 1':
        foo1()
    elif choice=='Choice 2':
        foo2()
    else:
        #do something else since they didn't press either
```

Pass `choice1` as the command for `Choice_1_Button`, `choice2` as the command for `Choice_2_Button`, and `start` for `Start_Button`.

If you want to use radio buttons, it will make it easier:

```
def start(choice):
    if choice=='Choice 1':
        foo1()
    elif choice=='Choice 2':
        foo2()
    else:
        #do something else since they didn't press either
var=StringVar(root)
var.set(None)
Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 1', value='Choice 1', variable=var).pack()
Radiobutton(root, text='Choice 2', value='Choice 2', variable=var).pack()
Button(self.frame, text='Start', command=lambda: start(var.get())).pack()
```