# How to use If-Statement inside the command of tkinter Button, to check that tkinter CheckButton is click or not?

Tags: python, if-statement, button, tkinter, lambda

## Program Summary

I'm making a python based text processing program. Here I am using following Tkinter widgets with following names for its GUI:

1. Text widget          >   "text_input"
2. Text widget          >   "text_output"
3. CheckButton widget   >   "checkButton_tense"
4. Button widget        >   "button_analyse"

And Now I wanted to my program to run in following sequence.

1. Taking text from "text_input".
2. Perform the some Basic Text Processing in some other class on clicking the "button_analyse" and show output in "text_output".
3. But if "checkButton_tense" widget is clicked/checked. Then it should also perform Tense Inspection along with basic text processing, else it should only perform basic text processing.
4. Above operation no. 3 should be performed after checking status of "checkButton_tense" widget on clicking the "button_analyse" and show output in "text_output"

## Problem/Error

Now when I use the if statement inside the "command=lambda:" of the my Tkinter Button "button_analyse" widget to check the status of "checkButton_tense" it gives me error. I have tried to do it with many ways but it don't works.

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50050440/python-tkinter-button-with-if-else-statements). But when I tried any solution like this i am unable to show my text in "text_output" widget because it is inside the different python method "main_gui_layout". I have also tried many other solutions given here at stack-overflow but don't found any identical. Kindly guide me in context of above mentioned problem and following code.

## Code

```
from tkinter import *
from Examples import Examples
from TextAnalysis import PerformTextAnalysis


class MyGui:
    useExamples = Examples()
    performTextAnalysis = PerformTextAnalysis()

def __init__(self, master):
    self.main_gui_layout(master)

def main_gui_layout(self, master):

    # InputBox to get the input Text.

    text_input = Text(master, bd=1, height=15, width=100)
    text_input.insert('end', self.useExamples.example2)
    text_input.pack(side=TOP)

    # OutputBox to show the processed Text.

    text_output = Text(master, bd=1, height=15, width=100)
    text_output.pack(side=TOP)

    # CheckButton: it will perform tense analysis if checked/clicked

    tenseCheck_clicked = IntVar()
    checkButton_tense = Checkbutton(master, text="Tense Inspection", variable=tenseCheck_clicked,
                                    bg='#9aa7bc')
    checkButton_tense.var = tenseCheck_clicked
    checkButton_tense.pack(side=TOP)

    # Analysis Button: it will process text and show in output.
    # It will also perform Tense Analysis if Above "checkButton_tense" is check/active.

    button_analyse = Button(master, text="Analyse Requirements", width=20,
                            command=lambda:
                            [
                                self.performTextAnalysis.get_userReqiurement(
                                str(text_input.get('1.0', 'end'))),
                                if tenseCheck_clicked == 1:
                                    ans = self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis(),
                                    self.performTextAnalysis.performTenseAnalysis(),
                                    text_output.insert(END, ans)
                                else:
                                self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis()

                            ])
    button_analyse.pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: why not just put your if-else statements in the callback function of `button_analyse`? you can then track if the `checkbutton_tense` is checked or not.

Comment: Don't build complex lambda functions. That is not what they are for. Just move all that to a standard function and then call that function with the button. Simple as that.

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 thanks for response. But the issue is -> when we make call backs then we need to make new methods for almost all callbacks. But when I make different functions then I also have to pass the "master" object of tk.root again and again to new methods which disturbs the layout of GUI. I don't know how to resolve it. I followed this way to make callbacks [Link] (http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) but it disturbs my GUI.

Comment: @Mike-SMT thanks for your response too. When I remove the lambdas. Then it become difficult for me to perform multiple operations by using single command. And when I make different functions using callbacks my GUI layout is disturbed. How can I call the object inside a function to other function without using return. I am confused. It is totally ambiguous don't know how to elaborate it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your `Examples` or `TextAnalysis` libraries so I cannot test functionality of them however I can provide an example using your code that should be good enough to show what we mean by "Move the lambda function to its own function".

You had a few things I would change like your class for one. Your class is more complex then it needs to be so lets remove the `main_gui_layout` method and just build the GUI in the `init` method. That said we can also inherit from the `Tk()` class so we can use `self` for the container of the widgets and class attributes.

Also I would change your tkinter import to `import tkinter as tk` as this will help prevent accidentally overwriting imports.

Se below example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from Examples import Examples
from TextAnalysis import PerformTextAnalysis


class MyGui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.useExamples = Examples()
        self.performTextAnalysis = PerformTextAnalysis()

        self.text_input = tk.Text(self, bd=1, height=15, width=100)
        self.text_input.insert('end', "self.useExamples.example2")
        self.text_input.pack(side='top')

        self.text_output = tk.Text(self, bd=1, height=15, width=100)
        self.text_output.pack(side='top')
        self.tenseCheck_clicked = tk.IntVar()

        checkButton_tense = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Tense Inspection", variable=self.tenseCheck_clicked, bg='#9aa7bc')
        checkButton_tense.var = self.tenseCheck_clicked
        checkButton_tense.pack(side='top')
        tk.Button(self, text="Analyse Requirements", width=20, command=self.new_function).pack(side='top')

    def new_function(self):
        self.performTextAnalysis.get_userReqiurement(str(self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')))
        if self.tenseCheck_clicked == 1:
            ans = self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis()
            self.performTextAnalysis.performTenseAnalysis()
            self.text_output.insert('end', ans)
        else:
            self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis()

MyGui().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution helped me a lot. It solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

You should't be putting that sort of logic in a `lambda`. The way tkinter is designed to work is that the button should call a function. Then it becomes trivial to add any logic you want.

You simply need to identify any widgets that need to be accessed in this function, and make them properties of the class.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
class MyGui:
    useExamples = Examples()
    performTextAnalysis = PerformTextAnalysis()

    def main_gui_layout(self, master):
        ...
        self.text_input = Text(master, bd=1, height=15, width=100)
        ....
        self.tenseCheck_clicked = IntVar()
        ...
        button_analyse = Button(master, text="Analyse Requirements", width=20,
                            command=self.on_button_click)

    def on_button_click(self, event):
        data = self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')
        self.performTextAnalysis.get_userReqiurement(data)
        if self.tenseCheck_clicked == 1:
            ans = self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis()
            self.performTextAnalysis.performTenseAnalysis()
            self.text_output.insert(END, ans)
        else:
            self.performTextAnalysis.performBasicAnalysis()
```